# Um actionListener para vários JButtons e vários JLabel

Tags: java, actionlistener

Gostaria de saber se há um jeito de reusar um código para vários jbuttons mudando o texto de vários labels. aqui está parte do código:

```
    petrificarSetaEsquerda = new JButton("");
    petrificarSetaEsquerda.addActionListener(actionListener);
    petrificarSetaEsquerda.setBounds(39, 58, 15, 15);
    petrificarSetaEsquerda.setBorder(emptyBorder);
    petrificarSetaEsquerda.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Mago.class.getResource("/mainPackage/left_arrow.png")));
    contentPane.add(petrificarSetaEsquerda);

    petrificarSetaDireita = new JButton("");
    petrificarSetaDireita.addActionListener(actionListener);
    petrificarSetaDireita.setBorder(emptyBorder);
    petrificarSetaDireita.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Mago.class.getResource("/mainPackage/right_arrow.png")));
    petrificarSetaDireita.setBounds(68, 58, 15, 15);
    contentPane.add(petrificarSetaDireita);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == petrificarSetaDireita){

                if (contadorPetrif <= 10 && contadorTotal > 0 ) {
                    lblPetrif.setText(String.format("%d", contadorPetrif++));
                    lblTotal.setText(String.format("Total : %d", contadorTotal--));
                }   
            }

            if(e.getSource() == petrificarSetaEsquerda){

                if (contadorPetrif > 0 && contadorTotal > 0) {
                    lblPetrif.setText(String.format("%d", contadorPetrif--));
                    lblTotal.setText(String.format("Total : %d", contadorTotal++));
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

o código tá executando normal,(tirando um probleminha que vou olhar depois) o foco aqui é se voces puderem me dar um dica de como reutilizar o código corretamente
No programa são 13Labels, e uma seta esquerda pra diminuir e uma seta direita para aumentar... Se prestarem atenção, o código sempre vai ser exatamente o mesmo para aumentar e diminuir o numero nos labels, só vai mudar os labels ...
Se não tiver vou ter que escrever 26 if seguidos... não parece certo colocar tanto código repetido assim

Alguém tem uma ideia? Código inteiro aqui : https://gist.github.com/91c1056d83c607c9e26d314be9285fa3

Comment: Os labels precisam mesmo terem nomes diferentes? Não pode ser algo como "label1, label2,...labelN"?

Comment: Na verdade não é obrigatório, só fiz isso pra facilitar a leitura do código @diegofm ...  parece que vc tem uma soluçao pra mim! heheh